# How to implement LinearLayout.replaceView() -- or ViewGroup.replaceView() in general

Tags: android, android-layout

Looking at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html), there is LinearLayout.addView() but there isn't any LinearLayout.replaceView().

On the other hand, there is [LinearLayout.removeView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29).

Is implementing my own LinearLayout.replaceView() as two simple successive calls to remove+add safe enough? i.e. are there caveats to watch for?

```
public void replaceView(View oldView, View newView) {
   removeView(oldView);
   addView(newView);
}
```

Comment: Looks valid. Why are you so doubtful?

Comment: It is valid only if the old view is the last view in the ViewGroup.

Comment: @ernazm See @OcuS's comment. Often times, things aren't as simple as they seem at 1st glance.

Comment: Agree. But i always find that things ain't so simple as they seem on practice. I mean you could deploy your solution and watch if it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void replaceView(final View oldView, final View newView) {
    addView(newView, indexOfChild(oldView));
    removeView(oldView);
}
```